# discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 40032): Target user is not connected to voice

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.9

here is my code in the bot

```
@Bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member,before,after): #Создание войс комнат
    if after:
        if after.channel:
            if after.channel.id == $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$:
                print(f'{member} зашёл в канал')
                for guild in Bot.guilds:
                    maincategory = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, id=$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$)
                    channel2 = await guild.create_voice_channel(name=f'{member.display_name}`s Channel',category = maincategory)
                    await channel2.set_permissions(member,connect=True,mute_members=True,move_members=True,manage_channels=True)
                    await member.move_to(channel2)
                    def check(x,y,z):
                        return len(channel2.members) == 0
                    await Bot.wait_for('voice_state_update',check=check)
                    await channel2.delete()
```

And this is my error in the terminal

```
Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Макс\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Макс\DRACULA-rms\bot.py", line 115, in on_voice_state_update
    await member.move_to(channel2)
  File "C:\Users\Макс\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 725, in move_to
    await self.edit(voice_channel=channel, reason=reason)
  File "C:\Users\Макс\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 668, in edit
    await http.edit_member(guild_id, self.id, reason=reason, **payload)
  File "C:\Users\Макс\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 254, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 40032): Target user is not connected to voice.
```

Please help me please, I can not solve this error myself, I use Python 39

Comment: if user is not connected to voide then you can you can connect to user. Always put it in `try/except` to catch error and skip this user.

Answer (score 0):

I see some errors in your code. I can't explain the error you mentioned, because there is no search for a specific user here/in your code.Let's look at the other things:

**First:** It is `bot.event`, not `Bot.event`, unless you defined it differently, then ignore this message. (*Code must then be adapted by you*)

While testing, I noticed that `for guild in Bot.guilds:` threw the following error:

```py
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 10003): Unknown Channel
```

I fixed this error by defining the `guild` directly:

```py
guild = bot.get_guild(GuildID):
```

I also restructured the code a bit and added a `discord.PermissionOverwrite` function to make it clearer.

**The full code:**

```py
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if after:
        if after.channel:
            if after.channel.id == AfterChannelID:
                print(f'{member} зашёл в канал')
                guild = bot.get_guild(GuildID)
                maincategory = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, id=CategoryID)
                overwrites = {
                    member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(connect=True, mute_members=True, move_members=True,
                                                        manage_channels=True)
                }
                channel2 = await guild.create_voice_channel(name=f'{member.display_name}',
                                                            category=maincategory, overwrites=overwrites)

                await member.move_to(channel2)

                def check(x, y, z):
                    return len(channel2.members) == 0

                await bot.wait_for('voice_state_update', check=check)
                await channel2.delete()
```

*The code then probably needs to be tweaked to your liking, but this one works fine for me.*

Comment: I did what you advised me to do, but now this error has come out:
`Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Макс\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Макс\DRACULA-rms\bot.py", line 111, in on_voice_state_update
    guild = bot.get_guild(GuildID)
AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands.bot' has no attribute 'get_guild' `

Comment: What is `discord.ext.commands.bot`? Use `from discord.ext import commands` Also you did not inser a guild ID into `GuildID`, this was just a filler...

Comment: And what should be specified in "GuildID"? Server ID?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned, same for all the other fillers I made that are undefined.

Comment: Cделал то что вы мне сказали, но всё равно появилась эта ошибка после выхода из комнаты.
`Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Макс\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Макс\DRACULA-rms\bot.py", line 111, in on_voice_state_update
    guild = bot.get_guild(660148058205716494)
AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands.bot' has no attribute 'get_guild' `

Comment: Do you have a link to the full code? I just know and use `from discord.ext import commands`. What `discord.py` version do you use? Please also just speak English...

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no link to the full code. I also use from discard. text import command, I use the version discord.py 3.9

Comment: It clearly comes from the imported module. You have to check that or upgrade/downgrade things. I never saw somebody using it so you may consider switchting and only use one module of this type.

Comment: Okay, can I get your telegram? I would send you a file with the code of this bot, and you would see what is wrong with it!